# VBA - Referencing a variable in a loop against a range of cells in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, syntax

I am trying to loop through a column of cells on sheet A & check if the value is present in a column in sheet B. If the value is present then I need the entire row in sheet A to be coloured orange. So far I have:

```
For Each Cell In Sheets(5).Range("A9:A" & LastRow)

    If Cell.Value = Sheets(6).Range(E2:E750) Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 44

    End If

Next Cell
```

The message error says that there is a syntax error on the IF line, however i have closed the 'If' so thats not it. I assume then it is something to do with the 'Sheets(6).Range(E2:E750)' reference.

I'm hoping this will be a quick fix but can't see the answer anywhere online.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some errors:

- `Range(E2:E750)` is an invalid `Range` syntax, while `Range("E2:E750")` is a valid one
- to check for some value occurrence in a range you want to use [`Find()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx) method of `Range` object

all what above could lead to:

```
With Sheets(6).Range("E2:E750") '<--| reference fully qualified lookup range
    For Each Cell In Sheets(5).Range("A9:A" & LastRow)
        If Not .Find(what:=Cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues) Is Nothing Then Cell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    Next Cell
End With
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, as always it seems to be simple Syntax that's letting me down. Due to time constraints I skipped over the basic lessons when teaching myself so I think I may have to re-visit...

Comment: Just one further question...
while this method works fine, some of the data I am referencing against in Sheets(6).Range("E2:E750") is not in the same format. 
This method works fine to reference my initial value (E.G '123') against the referenced range where there is a cell with exactly the same value. Is there any way of doing a wildcard search as such when for example the referenced value in the range = (E.G, '121 122 123 124 125') or = (E.G, '121,122,123,124,125')?

Comment: Change 'lookat:=xlWhole' to 'lookat:=xlPart'